# Count Rows According To Parameters VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I need to count how many instances or rows there are which have a specific value in one of the columns.

For Example:

the column "Ready" is a YES/NO column in Access.

If 5 rows have that set as YES and 7 have it as NO

how do i count how many have yes's and how many have no's

This is mainly for the purposes of statistics

Hope you get what i mean

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

```
select ready, count(*)
from a_table
group by ready
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already filled a datatable?

```
 Dim YesRows As Integer = MyTable.Rows.Count(Function(r) r("Ready") = 1)
```

Comment: How do i link this with MS Access? - i have a DB connection string just not sure how to use it with this